# Django tinyMC failed to load in admin panel

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I have problem with django-tinymce. This module doesnt load properly in admin panel and probably in normal form too. I used `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect static files. I'm running application with `debug = False`. I have 2 errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
```

You can see errors in [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e4pz.png).

Settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tinymce',
    ...
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '../public/static/') 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '../public/media/') 

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]


TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "tiny_mce")
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(TINYMCE_JS_ROOT, "tiny_mce.js")

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
}
```

and to urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    ...
]
```

EDIT

I update my code, I followed the instructions written by @dirkgroten and still got [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXVfY.png). [Here is a tree of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8kwZ.png). `settings.py` is in pystyle dir.

Comment: The `TINYMCE_JS_URL` is wrong, it needs to be `STATIC_URL + 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'` as you can see [here](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration). "root" is where the actual files are located on your storage device. "url" is the url used to fetch the resource over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

For all your static/media settings, remember this:

- `ROOT` is where files are physically located on the storage. Here you use things like `os.path.join` to build OS paths in file systems.
- `URL` is the url to use for fetching your resources over the internet. This gets processed by your server (nginx) which will translate it to the actual location of your files in order to return that file.

So your `TINYMCE_JS_URL` is wrong. It's not a path on your disk, it's a URL. It should be:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL + "tinymce/tinymce.js"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I still have problems. Look on main post, I updated it.

Comment: Is this in production?

Comment: What server are you using to serve your static files? Apache?

Comment: Probably nginx, but I don't know if I understood the question correctly. 
I stared and I run my server with debug = True, now I switch it to debug = False. And after your correct errors looks like before, on my first main post. [link]https://imgur.com/a/ILyyZaK

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3.1.

I have in code this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
```

Then I delete '/', and all start working:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

Then do

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Enjoy!